# Makefile for creating a library in Linux doesn't compile

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, makefile

I have 3 files , `my_pipe.h` , `my_pipe.c` , and `main.c`  , where `my_pipe` is supposed to be a library .

When I compile it in Eclipse , it compiles great , with no errors , but when I run the following `makefile` in `terminal` and hit `make` :

```
exer3:  main.o libmywrapper.a

    gcc main.c libmywrapper.a -o exer3 -static -lrt



libmywrapper.a: my_pipe.o

    ar rcs libmywrapper.a my_pipe.o



main.o: main.c my_pipe.h

    gcc -lpthread -lrt -c main.c



my_pipe.o:  my_pipe.c my_pipe.h

    gcc -lpthread -lrt -c my_pipe.c
```

I get this :

```
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop/myExer$ make
gcc -lpthread -lrt -c main.c
gcc -lpthread -lrt -c my_pipe.c
ar rcs libmywrapper.a my_pipe.o
gcc main.c libmywrapper.a -o exer3 -static -lrt
libmywrapper.a(my_pipe.o): In function `shm_pipe_init':
my_pipe.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `sem_init'
libmywrapper.a(my_pipe.o): In function `shm_pipe_read':
my_pipe.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
my_pipe.c:(.text+0x196): undefined reference to `sem_getvalue'
my_pipe.c:(.text+0x1ba): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
libmywrapper.a(my_pipe.o): In function `shm_pipe_write':
my_pipe.c:(.text+0x4b7): undefined reference to `sem_post'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [exer3] Error 1
```

Any idea what's wrong with the makefile ?

Thanks

**UPDATED , above!**

Comment: Looks like the other targets aren't built yet or is this just a rerun?

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx: Nothing was built.

Comment: Have you tried placing -lpthread last on command line? I found the order to be relevant. Also, I understand that you might need only -lpthread and not -lrt?

Comment: Can you please remove all the object files, including the library, and make again. It may be helpful to have the full build output

Comment: @lserni: When I compile in eclipse , it demands both . Furthermore , I've tried to put `-lpthread` at the end and the same result it displayed .

Comment: Try building all the other objects first then, I'm not sure this implicit "all" target works, since it tries to build exer3 immediately, without looking at the dependencies.

Comment: You should never use `-lpthread` directly when linking. Use `-pthread` instead for both compiling and linking. That takes care of adding any platform-specific flags that the preprocessor, compiler and linker may need to build multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linker options such as `-lpthread` and `-lrt` must go last in you compile line. Try:

```
gcc main.o libmywrapper.a -o exer3 -static -lrt
```

When compiling, you don't need linker flags. E.g.:

```
main.o: main.c my_pipe.h
  gcc -c main.c
```

Comment: btw: it should be `main.o` in the linking step, not `main.c`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution :

```
exer3:  main.o sharedMemoryLib.a

    gcc main.o sharedMemoryLib.a -o exer3 -static -lrt -lpthread



sharedMemoryLib.a:  my_pipe.o

    ar rcs sharedMemoryLib.a my_pipe.o



main.o: main.c my_pipe.h

    gcc -c main.c



my_pipe.o:  my_pipe.c my_pipe.h

    gcc -c my_pipe.c
```

Comment: you don't need linker flags when compiling and you should use the freshly compiled `main.o` when linking

Comment: the last compiler step lines can just read: `gcc -c main.c`.The `-lpthread -lrt` are only necessary when linking.

Comment: You (=Ron, the original poster of the question) really should learn more about GNU `make` and the many implicit rules and variables it is using like `CFLAGS`  etc

Comment: Run `make -p` to have an idea of all the rules (and variables) `make` knows about.... Then read the documentation

Comment: Looks good to me. Of course there's a lot of magic that you can do with makefiles. E.g. put `gcc -c $<` when compiling. But it is also a good way of loosing time ;)

Comment: May you please point me to a good `makefile` tutorial !!! I always wanted to learn C, so started playing with it recently, just couldn't find one good tutorial related to `makefile`. If you could point me to it, I shall be very thankful :-)

Comment: @nIcE cOw : that one helped me quite a lot : http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html

Comment: @ron : Thankyou for this link :-) will look now into this, I am too new to C, so cannot say much, hope you might will help, just in case :-)